# Двумерный массив

Tags: javascript, массивы

Как в двумерный массив вставить числа по возрастанию в стоблце?
То есть

```
0  4  8
1  5  9
2  6 10
3  7
```

```js
function ll(num, col) {
  var n = Math.ceil(num / col);

  var mas = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    mas[i] = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < col; j++) {
      mas[i][j] = num;
    }
  }
  return mas;
}
console.log(ll(10, 3));
```

Comment: Вы делаете так, `mas[i][j] = num;` и что же хотите получить в результате? Впихиваете везде первый параметр функции.

Comment: Что должна делать функция `ll`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function ll(num, cols) {
  var n = Math.ceil((num + 1) / cols);

  var res = [];

  for (var q=0; q<n; ++q) {
    res.push([]);
  }
  
  for (var q=0; q<=num; ++q) {
    res[q%res.length].push(q);
  }

  return res;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(ll(10, 3)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(ll(11, 3)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(ll(12, 3)));
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 2):

> mas[i][j] = num;

Вот тут нужно заменить num на то, что вам нужно

- i*(n-1)+j - по строкам
- j*n+i - по столбцам

```js
function ll (num, cols){
        var rows = Math.ceil((num+1)/cols);

        var mas = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++){
            mas[i] = [];
            for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++){
              mas[i][j] = j*rows+i;
        }}
        return mas;
      }
      console.log(ll(10,3));
```

Если же нужно выводить не прямоугольную матрицу (без 11) - можно попросту прерывать цикл по условию ">10"

```js
function ll (num, cols){
        var rows = Math.ceil((num+1)/cols);

        var mas = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++){
            mas[i] = [];
            for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++){
              let number = j*rows+i;
              if (number > num) break; 
              mas[i][j] = number;
        }}
        return mas;
      }
      console.log(ll(10,3));
```

В последнем массиве видим искомые [3, 7]

Comment: Ему надо по столбцам, а не по строкам. И без 11.

Comment: @Qwertiy, уговорил, чертяка =)

Comment: `var rows = Math.ceil(num/cols);` - это неверно. Записывается на одно число больше, поэтому на `ll(12, 3)` получится лишний столбец. UPDATE: Точнее, число 12 просто не попадёт в результат при твоём способе заполнения.

Comment: Это "почти верно" =) Проблема в том, что первый аргумент - не число элементов, а максимум. Включая 0, число элементов num+1.

Comment: Ну да :) У меня в коде `+1` - понял когда писал `<=` :)

Answer (score 0):

вы постоянно присваиваете всем элементам массива одно и тоже значение num: **mas[i][j] = num;** **эту строчку следует изменить на mas[i][j] = i*n+j** и если я правильно понял задачу, то еще и изменить граничные условия цикла. При этом на выходе в mas будут лежать столбцы в виде массивов.

```js
 function ll (num, col){
            var n = Math.ceil(num/col);

            var mas = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < col; i++){
                mas[i] = [];
                for (var j = 0; j < n; j++){
                  mas[i][j] = i*n+j;
            }}
            return mas;
          }
          console.log(ll(10,3));
```

Comment: Ему надо по столбцам, а не по строкам. И без 11.

Comment: не совсем, я как ра не могу придумать, как вывести именно числовой массив в виде
 0  4  8<br />
 1  5  9<br />
 2  6 10<br />
 3  7 
то есть вывод 123 не в строке а именно в столбце

Comment: @Ирина Не понял. В вопросе было **Не получается засунуть в него числа по возрастанию в стоблце** Так вопрос не в массиве, а в отображении? Результат **console.log(ll(10,3));** должен быть строкой: **0 4 8<br /> 1 5 9<br /> 2 6 10<br /> 3 7** ?

Comment: @tilin, бберём массив в 4 строки и последовательно добавляем в его столбцы числа, пока не дойдём до num. [[], [], [], []] => [[0], [1], [2], [3]] => [[0,4], [1,5], [2,6], [3,7]] => [[0,4,8], [1,5,9], [2,6,10], [3,7]] - 11 не добавилось, т. к. дошли до переданного ограничения. Это же есть в вопросе... UPDATE: Не из 4 строк, а из необходимого количества строк для получения заданного числа столбцов.